# Creating a custom method of a System Type

Tags: c#

I am just curious if there is a way of adding a method to the system type i.e.

```
char.IsNull(value)
```

i know a similar thing can be achieved by using an extension method but to call that i have to put `'M'.IsNull()`

Comment: With an extension method you *don't* have to specify the type. It's easier to use than what you want to do.

Comment: You want to write `char.IsNull(value)` instead of `value.IsNull()` or `MoreChar.IsNull(value)`? What should happen if we add the feature and then new methods with identical signatures are added in two different places in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, basically; there is an *ongoing discussion* (titled "extension everything") on the topic of whether to add such a feature, but right now (including the current C# 8 previews): no.